# A good alernative to WebBrowser component?

Tags: .net, browser, webkit, components

*I know that there is a WebBrowser component which is basically Internet Explorer but I'm highly dissatisfied with the amount of features it has + Internet Explorer's layout engine is terrible.*

**Is there a better alternative to that? Something like a "*Gecko*" or a "*Webkit*" browser?** I tried "Skybound Gecko" but I'm sure there are some better implementations. It would also help if it would be **lightweight** (for redistribution) and **wouldn't rely on user's computer configuration (such as 'is firefox installed')**

Comment: What was wrong with Skybound Gecko? It's as lightweight as any solution that is built off of Gecko. And it doesn't rely on the user's computer configuration (so long as you include it with your installer, which seems the reasonable thing to do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read [Embedding Gecko(Mozilla rendering engine) in a .Net application](http://weblogs.asp.net/mspedding/archive/2004/07/19/187580.aspx):

> Over the weekend I had some spare
>   time, so I thought  I wonder if you
>   can use the Mozilla rendering
>   engine(Gecko) within a .Net
>   application as easily as you can IE ?
>   This could be important in areas where
>   people have concerns about using IE.
>   It turns out it is as simple as a
>   download, add COM component to the
>   toolbar and if required adding a
>   reference to the project. Even the
>   intereface has been modelled on the IE
>   model to make it simple to use. It is
>   of cause unmanaged code but it works.

And also [WebKit .NET](https://www.ohloh.net/p/webkitdotnet):

> WebKit .NET is a control library
>   wrapper for WebKit written in C#. The
>   aim is to make it easy for users to
>   incorporate WebKit into their .NET
>   applications.